# How to display photos by rating with Ruby on Rails framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok. I've got a model Picture

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :rating
  has_many :comments
end
```

And, of course Rating model

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture
end
```

I made rating system by myself. So, now on the frontpage I need to display all photos by rating. Please, can u show me how to do that. I've no idea what will be in index.html.erb of main controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Rating has an integer field "value", you can do this:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :rating

  named_scope :by_rating, { :joins => :rating, :order => 'ratings.value DESC' }
end
```

Now, in the controller you can use this:

```
@pictures_top10 = Picture.by_rating.all :limit => 10
```

In the view:

```
<% @pictures_top10.each do |picture| %>
  <%= image_tag(picture.url) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tnanks, but i need to get fields from table Ratings in result!

Comment: Including Rating columns is possible, too:

    named_scope :by_rating, { :joins => :rating, :order => 'ratings.value DESC', :select => 'pictures.*, ratings.*' }